# Python call function defined in class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So I am making a game and I am using Tkinter and Python 2.7, and I want to store map data in files. I am trying to make a menu to open the file and set to a variable. I am having trouble defining a function to use on the Tkinter Button.

The Tkinter window opens but when I click the button it gives an error.

Code:

```
#readfiles.py
class maps(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data
    def mapset(var):
        data = var
fselect = Tk()
...
buttons = Frame(fselect).pack()
Label(fselect, text="Select maps in folder:")
for i in listdir('./maps/'):
    if i[-4:] == ".pvm":
        Button(buttons, text=i[:-4], command=lambda i=i: mapset(open('./maps/'+i, 'r').read())).pack()
```

`NameError: global name 'mapset' is not defined`

Also, how can I access the `data` variable in `maps` (so it would be `maps.data`, right) in another file?

```
#main.py
from readfiles import *
print maps.data
```

`AttributeError: type object 'maps' has no attribute 'data'`

Let me know if you need any additional information.
Also, `print "Happy New Years!`

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Is ```mapset``` an attribute of ```maps```?

Comment: Looks like `def mapset(var):` and its body need to be indented once more

Comment: You never call the `maps()` function to create an object. And `self.data` should be `self.data = something`.

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code you posted. As Barmar mentions, you never create a `maps` instance, and the `maps.__init__` method doesn't make sense. What is `mapset` supposed to do? Is it supposed to be a method of `maps`? Also, the `widget.pack` and `.grid` methods return `None`, so `buttons = Frame(fselect).pack()` sets `buttons` to `None`. And you forgot to `.pack` that `Label` widget.

Comment: @wwii and andy that was just a typo

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for reminding me about packing the `Label`.

Comment: Also @PM2Ring, the whole purpose of 'mapset' and the 'Button' in the for + if statement is to select a file from a list (`listdir('./maps/')`), read the file, and store the data. I make a button that stores the argument `open('./maps/'+i, 'r').read()` to the variable `data`. Is there a better way to do this because otherwise I'm lost.

Comment: Which "variable `data`" are you referring to? There is no such variable. `data` is the name of an attribute you seem to want to have in the `maps` class, but you never actually create an instance of that class, or assign anything to the variable properly. I think your TK code is not the main problem you're having. Rather, it's obscuring your confusion about basic OOP concepts. Try reading over [the Python tutorial's chapter on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and then see if you can sort it out.

Comment: Surely you want to store the map data in some kind of collection, eg a list or a dict. I suggest you follow Blckkight's advice & do some more study about classes. IMHO, this program would benefit from building the whole GUI in a class, rather than just using a class to store the maps. There are plenty examples showing how to do that here on SO in the Tkinter tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple GUI class that stores the data from a map file in the `self.data` attribute.

To test this code I created a set of simple text files using this Bash command:

```bash
for i in {0..5}; do echo >"maps/map${i}.pvm" "Map $i data"; done
```

And here's the Python 3 code. To run it on Python 2, just change the Tkinter import statement to `import Tkinter as tk`, and add `from __future__ import print_function` before the other import statements.

I've added a `"Print data"` that lets us test that we have actually loaded the data correctly.

```python
import tkinter as tk
import os

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self, mapspath):
        self.data = None

        root = tk.Tk()
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        tk.Label(frame, text="Select maps in folder:").pack()

        for fbase in os.listdir(mapspath):
            if fbase.endswith('.pvm'):
                fname = os.path.join(mapspath, fbase)
                #print(fname)
                tk.Button(frame, text=fbase[:-4], 
                    command=lambda fn=fname:self.read_map(fn)).pack()

        tk.Button(frame, text="Print data", command=self.print_map).pack()

        root.mainloop()

    def read_map(self, fname):
        with open(fname) as f:
            self.data = f.read()

    def print_map(self):
        print("current map:", self.data)

Gui("./maps")
```

Unless these maps are huge it would probably be more convenient to store all of them at once. You could store them in a list, but it'd probably be better to store them in a dictionary, using the base name (minus the `'.pvm'` extension) as the key.